# Save SQL result into python list/tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have SQL to work within python. Writing code to where I need to save play with the SQL results and But the challenge here is the performance. I am not able to get the List from SQL result in acceptable parameters.

I don't have many things, I don't have any clue what could help me

```
cur =  connection.cursor() opening cursor
list = [] initializing list
cur.execute("select * from table ")  # 86000 records
print("Start date: {}".format(date time))
for i in cur.fetch_all():
    list.append(i)
print("Start date: {}".format(date time))
```

RESULT :

```
Start date: 2019-08-17 16:34:23.808323
Start date: 2019-08-17 16:38:19.828673
```

It should be done in max 10 seconds. Query returned 86000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cur =  connection.cursor() opening cursor
cur.execute("select * from table ")  # 86000 records
print("Start date: {}".format(date time))
list = [x for x in cur.fetch_all()]
print("Start date: {}".format(date time))
```

Comment: fetchall() is again becomes the culprit. It takes same amount of time to fetch all 86000 records

Comment: How long it takes to run currently (in python)? And, if you run the same query in your DB's client interface, how long does it take?

Comment: DB query is giving result in micro seconds. No issues with the DB performance only how to iterate over the result set.